# Process and plot data in different files using pfgplots

Tags: pgfplots

I like to read in my x-y-data from different files and then process them somehow. I read different questions here on each topic ([data using from different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141085/pst-plot-x-y-data-from-different-files) and [processing data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122962/reading-and-processing-data-in-pgfplots)) but I somehow can't manage throwing them together. The following MWE works but I can't process the data. I loaded the x-y-data seperately into \xData and \yData but I can't get them to be plotted as they are seperated. The data I can get plotted I can't process...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/y/.style={create col/copy column from table={chi_probe.dat}{0}}
}

\pgfplotstableread{grid_omega_opt.dat}\xData;
\pgfplotstableread{chi_probe.dat}\yData;

\begin{axis}[
width=0.85\linewidth,
height=8cm
]

\addplot[black, smooth] table [y=y] {grid_omega_opt.dat};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "process the data" ?

Comment: In addition to explaining in more detail what you mean by "process the data", could you also edit your question to include some dummy data?

Comment: I think the @Jake's answer to [edit x-y data from different files/tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67088/31093) solves your problem